# Numero symbol instead of the word 'no' being typeset with a certain font

Tags: fonts, symbols, memoir

I have the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Nimbus Sans L}

\begin{document}
No, no, Not, not.
\end{document}
```

The font I am using can be obtained from [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/nimbus-sans-l). When this finishes processing, the 'No's (both the standalone and the non-standalone) are processed as [numero signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign) for some reason. I checked and found that this *only* happened with this font ([Liberation Sans](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/liberation-sans), another font I tested, did not have this issue). What on earth is going on, and how can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For strange reasons, the font enables a `No` ligature: this is a very nasty feature, as you discovered.

You can disable it by adding `Ligatures=NoCommon`; since f-ligatures are not used anyway, you should be OK with this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*regular,
  ItalicFont=*italic,
  BoldFont=*bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*bold-italic,
  Ligatures=NoCommon,
]{nimbus-sans-l_}

\begin{document}

No, no, Not, not, firefly, flagstaff

\end{document}
```

Note: the font setup is made in that way because I didn't want to add the font in my system.

[image]